# Android Application crash if same image selected second time from SDCard

Tags: android, listview, sd-card

What my application do is that it simply take image from sdcard and shows in a listview.When i select image from sdcard it displays correctly in listview, But when i select same image second time from sdcard , applcation crashes. What i want, if same image is selected second time it should give toast  that image already exists. Thanks for helping

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Bitmap image=(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            addattachmentsToListView(image);

            cursor.close();
```

Comment: post your logcat values

Comment: is that outOfMemory error?

Answer (score 1):

First @A.S. may be right because the selected image may be too large to be loaded into memory. Second thing you asked about loading one image only once is, you should save the url, id or something of last loaded item so that before loading you can check that is it the same thing that I already have. If so, don't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a OutOfMemory Exception. It is a bit difficult to read bigger Images from a SD Card, but fortunately the Android Developers site gives you a detailed tutorial to avoid this exception: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

> This lesson walks you through decoding large bitmaps without exceeding the per application memory limit by loading a smaller subsampled version in memory.

[Up to the lesson](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)